# Get runtime properties of the same element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When we enter text in google search text box it auto-suggest the options,the objects are changes. Now I want to click the "Search" button which was earlier "Google Search".I have created the "Google Search" button with name property and "btnK" is the value.Now as the property is changed to "btnG",how I can retrieve the properties and then use this property value to identify the object. This sounds like dead-end because object is changed so we cannot retrieve its value. I believe we can use dynamic property here. But I am stuck here!! I am using selenium web driver and Java.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use previous property as its a behavior of application and so you need to instruct  selenium accordingly. Although there is one solution for which you need to use "Multiple Criteria xpath "

Use this xpath for your click operation

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='btnG' or @name='btnK']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0")).gettext(); // this will retrieve your value from text box
```

This way if selenium find any one of element then it will click on same.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I don't want to retrieve text from the text box,instead I want to retrieve the value of any property of the button. I think the first xpath can be used to identify the element second time but no sure. Thanks... will try to execute this!! @Shubaham

Comment: @Shubham-Thanks a lot!! The xpath works and i am also able to retrieve other properties of the button!!  One question here- I have already given the property "btnG".What if we are not aware of this property so how do we handle the problem in that case.

Comment: welcome mojo . we to need locate element somehow to perform operation on it. xpath provide you some more flexible to locate the element like instead of locate button from name='btnG' you can also use //button[@class='lsb'][@type='submit']. Now at the end even if this element also change then we need to change our script too that's also called maintainence of scripts